# Missing corners on a square lattice

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics, computation

As can be seen in Figure[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OCi1.png). I am trying to plot a square lattice in python.

Somehow I am missing the corner points.
The code is working fine for 3x3 square lattice but it's not for 5x5 and the situation gets worse if I further increase lmax.

for 3x3, lmax is 1,
for 5x5, lmax is 2,
for 7x7, lmax is 3, and so on

Sample code is given.
My question is how do I get those missing points and plot them.
With this code, I am getting missing points on the top and bottom left corners.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lmax = 2
nnb = 4
a = 1
lmin = -lmax
site_pos = [[0,0]]
nsites = int(((lmax-lmin)/a+1)**2)
a = 1
vectors = np.array([[a,0],[0,-a],[-a,0],[0,a]])


x = []       
y = []
for site in range(nsites):   
    for nbd in range(nnb):
        origin = site_pos[site]
        pos = origin+vectors[nbd]
        if (pos[0] > lmax or pos[0] < lmin or pos[1] > lmax or pos[1] < lmin): # boundaries fixed within lmax and lmin
            continue
        else:
            site_pos.append(pos)
        x.append(pos[0])
        y.append(pos[1])

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[square_full](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OCi1.png)

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient code (many lattice sites are being plotted multiple times). Why do you expect it to work at all? Try to write down its pseudocode, or print x and y after each append and you'll see the problem.